# Opening a ctools modal on form submit

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

I have a custom profile form (part of a multi-step registration process) that requires a modal to be displayed once submitted. I am not clear on what the process is for this to happen, and the documentation i've seen isn't clear.

What I have tried (as seen below) is adding the submit action via a $form['#action'] which only returns the JS Object for the modal. Clearly, this isn't working. What should I do to render this modal when the form submits, while assuring the validation and submit calls fire?

The actual Ctools Modal logic is in its own modal, of which it generates on a hook_menu() call to the correct route.

```
function example_profile_update_form($form, $form_state) {
  $form = array();

  $form['item'] = array(
    "#type" => 'textfield',
  );

  $form['#validate'][] = "example_profile_update_validate";
  $form['#action'] = url("modal/updated/nojs"); //Implemented as a hook_menu() call in its own module
  $form['#submit'][] = "example_profile_update_submit";

  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Form API and Ajax frameworks work quite well together.

In your submit button, that you want to trigger the popup, it should work as an Ajax element first.

```
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Submit (and open popup)',
);
```

If you use submit and validate handlers as you have shown in your question, those submit and validate handlers will be executed at this point. If you want different submit/validate handlers, then you have to add them to the submit button itself.

Now, add `#ajax` property to the element.

```
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Submit (and open popup)',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'wrapper' => 'id_of_some_unique_element',
    'callback' => 'my_module_give_this_function_a_nice_name',  
  ),
);
ctools_include('modal');
ctools_modal_add_js();
```

We play a trick here. Typically, `#ajax` property is used to replace some parts of the form. That's why we use the wrapper to indicate the **replacing** element. This will not be used at all if you trigger the modal, but make sure you refer to a unique DIV. Better leave it empty.

The `callback` is what we need. This callback should be a PHP function name, that returns some or full `$form` first parameter, **or**, it can print some Ajax commands. Do **not** set `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE` in your `#submit` handler.

`ctools_add_modal_js()` adds the modal.js file because it's necessary to trigger the popup.

```
function my_module_give_this_function_a_nice_name($form, &$form_state) {
  // this function gets the $form_state after submitting the form. All values, including the submitted values preserved. 
}
```

Now, we need to print the modal contents.

```
function my_module_give_this_function_a_nice_name($form, &$form_state) {
  // this function gets the $form_state after submitting the form. All values, including the submitted values preserved. 
  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_modal_add_js();
  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ctools_modal_command_display('title', 'modal content goes here');
  // You can add extra modal using drupal_add_js/css. You can also have them `#attached` to a rendarable array that you are going to print. 
  print ajax_render($commands);
  exit;
}
```